# Serializer en Django

Tags: api, backend, djangorestframework, serialización

Quiero preguntar si esto esta bien ... para poder agregar user al serializar
esto esta correcto o es mala practica ?
segun la documentacion creo que se usa los metodos create o update pero no estoy seguro
modelos:
class User(AbstractUser):
profile_image = models.ForeignKey(ProfileImage, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
related_name='users', null=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Si se proporciona una contraseña y no está encriptada, encriptarla
        if self.password and not self.password.startswith('pbkdf2_'):
            self.set_password(self.password)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Usuario"
        verbose_name_plural = "Usuarios"
        ordering = ["-date_joined"]
        db_table = "tabla_usuario"

class LotteryForUserModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    number_phone = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
```

serializer:

```
class LotteryForUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = LotteryForUserModel
        fields = ('user','address', 'number_phone')
```

views.py
class LotteryView(APIView):
authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
def post (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
user, token = JWTAuthentication().authenticate(request)
print(user.id)
if user is not None:
data = request.data.copy()
data["user"] = user.id
data_serializer = LotteryForUserSerializer(data=data)

```
            print('-----', data_serializer)
            if data_serializer.is_valid():
                data_serializer.save()
            return Response({'message':'Registrado correctamente'}, status = status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        return Response({'error':'error al registrarse'}, status = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```